# How to pass regular expression matching string from a file in awk?

Tags: regex, awk

I have a requirement where I have to split a large file into small files. Each line of the large file containing the matching string should be put into another file with the output file name same as the matching string. For one string I can get it done via **awk** as shown below.

```
awk '/apple/{print}' large_file.txt > apple.txt
```

I want a script which takes the regular expression matching string from another file and puts the results into a file with the same name as the matching string. How to get it done with awk command?

Let's say the string to be matched is put into a file called matching_string.txt the contents of which would look like this:

```
apple
orange
mango
```

If the large_file.txt is something like:

```
apple is a great fruit
we should eat apple
orange is juicy
mango is the king of fruits
litchi is a seasonal fruit
```

then the resulting file should be

apple.txt:

```
apple is a great fruit
we should eat apple
```

orange.txt:

```
orange is juicy
```

mango.txt:

```
mango is the king of fruits
```

I am new to the Linux environment and beginner level at scripting. Any other solution using regular expression, sed, python etc. should be also okay.

**EDIT**

Working Script:

I tweaked my script a little based on the answer by @Stephen Quan, it works for the tsch shell.

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
foreach word ("`cat pattern.txt`")
  if (-r ${word}.txt) then
    rm -rf  ${word}.txt
  endif
  awk "/${word}/ { print }" large.txt > ${word}.txt
end
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts as code, keep it up. Looks like you have given very generic samples here, could you please do add more relevant samples in your question to make it more clear, thank you

Comment: I am looking at a concept which works for any set of data, to explain the question I have given a sample. In the actual scenario, I have a huge file with tens of thousands of entries related to the synthesized netlist of an SoC(VLSI Domain) and I have to split the data based on sub-components of the SoC. The number of lines in the netlist and the number of sub-components in SoC may vary from one chip to another so, I am looking for a dynamic solution.

Comment: @Aditya Your "working" script will fail for patterns containing whitespace (spaces, tabs). Deleting the file shouldn't be required, because `>` will overwrite existing files (at least it does in POSIX shells). `awk '/pattern/{print}` is a complicated way of writing `grep 'pattern'`.

Comment: IIRC there is a "force overwrite" redirect in `tcsh` `>!` ... but really, sane people abandoned `tcsh` around 30 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in `awk`:

```
for word in $(cat matching_string.txt)
do
awk "/${word}/ { print }" large_file.txt > ${word}.txt
done
```

```bash
while IFS= read -r word
do
  if [ -f ${word}.txt ]; then rm ${word}.txt; fi
  awk "/${word}/ { print }" large_file.txt > ${word}.txt
done < matching_string.txt
```

The pattern is a regex pattern followed by a command. Note that when you get into regex-capture groups, you may find that the implementation of awk varies from one platform to another.

If it is a simplistic regex, I prefer `perl` because in cross-platform environments (particularly osx and git-bash on Windows), `perl` has a more consistent implementation for regex handling. In this case, the `perl` solution would be:

```bash
while IFS= read -r word
do
  if [ -f ${word}.txt ]; then rm ${word}.txt; fi
  perl -ne "if (/${word}/) { print }" < large_file.txt > ${word}.txt
done < matching_string.txt
```

I wanted to also demonstrate capture groups. In this case, it is a bit of over-engineered to represent your line as 3 capture groups (prefix, word, postfix), but, I do this because it serves as a template for you to create more complex regex capture group processing scenarios:

```bash
while IFS= read -r word
do
  if [ -f ${word}.txt ]; then rm ${word}.txt; fi
  perl -ne "if (/(.*)(${word})(.*)/) { print $1$2$3 . '\n' }" < large_file.txt > ${word}.txt
done < matching_string.txt
```

Comment: I have edited the script to cater to tcsh shell, created a cshrc file with content:
`#!/bin/csh -f
foreach word ("`cat pattern.txt`")
  awk "/${word}/ { print }" large.txt > ${word}.txt
end  `

This is getting the work done. Although if the filename ${word}.txt exists, then the script is saying the file already exists. need to remove the files if they already exist. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Stephen : `perl` is also frequently slower than `awk`, sometimes by a rather painful margin, so there's that

Comment: All of your loops are going to fail if one of the patterns in `matching_string.txt` contains space or tab characters. See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765). `for` comes with a lot more problems than `while` in this aspect.

Comment: @knittl I will do some pre-processing on the matching_string.txt to ensure that tab and whitespace are removed, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Aditya also make sure your pattern's do not contain `/` when embedding them inside `awk`. If you are really only looking for substring matches (without [tag:regular-expressions]), then `grep -F`/`fgrep` might be the better alternative

Comment: sure @knittl, I will try to optimize the solution with other alternatives.

Comment: See also bash pitfalls: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: Answer will fail as soon as a pattern contains blanks, because variables are not quoted. Redirecting to multiple files will fail.

Answer (score 2):

Why use awk? Grep does the job too. Usually, `awk '/pattern/{print}'` can be replaced by the shorter `grep -e 'pattern'`.

```
pattern=apple
grep -e "$pattern" large.txt > "$pattern.txt"
```

Write a script or a shell function. For instance, a simple shell function can be defined ad-hoc and then called.

```
filter() { grep -e "$1" large.txt > "$1.txt"; }
for pattern in apple orangle mango; do filter "$pattern"; done
```

As a shell script (e.g. `filter.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
grep -e "$1" large.txt > "$1.txt"
```

Needless to say, the script file must have the executable bit set, otherwise it cannot be executed (obviously).

Assuming your pattern file (e.g. `pattern.txt`) contains one pattern per line:

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r pattern <&3; do
  filter "$pattern"
  # or: ./filter.sh "$pattern"
done 3< pattern.txt
```

All of that can be done without script or function if you simply want a one-shot task to be done (but defining and using the function is not really more complicated than calling its body directly):

```
while IFS= read -r pattern <&3; do
  grep -e "$pattern" large.txt > "$pattern.txt"
done 3< pattern.txt
```

Note that a `for` loop cannot be used here, since your program will break as soon as one of your patterns contains space or tab characters.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248619/discussion-on-answer-by-knittl-how-to-pass-regular-expression-matching-string-fr).

Answer (score 1):

use grep -e pattern:

```
pattern=orange
grep -e "$pattern" large.txt > "$pattern.txt"
```

then use the read command to read all Patterns and generate all files:

```
filename='patternfile.txt'
while read pattern; do
grep -e "$pattern" large.txt > "$pattern.txt"
done < $filename
```